# Problems of MORSE Simulator installation with python version on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, simulator

My problem:
 Blender is compiled for Python 3.5.1 but MORSE has been compiled for Python 3.3.6! Check your MORSE build configuration or the selected Blender version.

- Bad Python version
- Your environment is not correctly setup to run MORSE!
  It seems that both of them are compulsory for the python version. So when I uninstalled python 3.3 and install 3.5 and the morse cannot work.

Comment: Why not compile MORSE against Python 3.5.1 then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, except it was a much narrower version gap:

```
Blender is compiled for Python 3.4.2 but MORSE has been compiled for Python 3.4.3! Check your MORSE build configuration or the selected Blender version.
```

This was for Blender `2.76`. You may get this to work if you use an older version of blender that bundles a `3.3.x` version of python.

Open `path/to/morse/bin/morse.in` in your favorite editor. Find the function `check_blender_python_version`, modify it to return None:

```
def check_blender_python_version(blender_path):
    """ Creates a small Python script to execute within Blender and get the
    current Python version bundled with Blender
    """
    return None
```

Then rebuild morse and re-install

This disables the version check, which is not ideal, but assuming you've already verified that both are using the same minor version of Python, it should work. In my case, I can run simulations etc. without issue.