# Issue with setting up correct Blender environent for MORSE on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, blender, python-3.8, ompl

I'm at my wits end with this thing.  For a class project I wanted to use [MORSE](https://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/stable/user/installation.html) simulator due to its compatibility with OMPL.  But trying to get this thing set up has been such a pain in the neck.  First I tried it the simple way with:

```
sudo apt-get install morse-simulator
```

But when I do the check command to see if everything is ok I get this:

```
* Checking up your environment...


* Running on Linux. Alright.

* Found MORSE libraries in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/morse/blender'. Alright.

* Trying to figure out a prefix from the script location...

* Default scene found. The prefix seems ok. Using it.

* Setting $MORSE_ROOT environment variable to default prefix [/usr/local/]

* Checking version of /usr/bin/blender... Found v.2.82.7

* Version 2.82.7 of Blender is untested but should work

* Found Blender in your PATH
(/usr/bin/blender, v.2.82.7).
Alright, using it.

* Checking version of Python within Blender /usr/bin/blender... Found v.3.8.1

* Blender is compiled for Python 3.8.1 but MORSE has been compiled for Python 3.8.10! Check your MORSE build configuration or the selected Blender version.

* Bad Python version

* Your environment is not correctly setup to run MORSE!
```

So I try to see if I could download a separate blender and try and route the environment through there.   I followed the example given [here](https://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/stable/user/faq.html) about editing the .bashrc file.  Currently my .bashrc has `export MORSE_BLENDER=/home/antonio/software/blender_software/blender` at the end of it.  Still references the one in /usr/bin when I check again.

Next I try manually installing morse.  I follow the instructions to the letter, but for some reason now it won't recognize morse at all.  This was after I removed the morse that I downloaded with sudo apt-get.

Finally I re-download using sudo apt-get and try to go in and manually adjust the morse.py file within /usr/bin so that it reads the directory of my other blender.  I have it like this

```
#MORSE prefix (automatically detected) (On line 55)
morse_prefix = ""
#Path to Blender executable (automatically detected)
blender_exec = "/home/antonio/software/blender_software/blender"
#Path to MORSE default scene (automatically detected)
default_scene_abspath = ""


 #Check Blender version (On line 242)
    #First, look for the $MORSE_BLENDER env variable
    try:
        #blender_exec = os.environ['MORSE_BLENDER']
        version = check_blender_version(blender_exec)
        if version:
```

I commented out where blender_exec was reassigned to os.environ['MORSE_BLENDER']  Still nothing.

So what do I even do?  I know there's this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691523/problems-of-morse-simulator-installation-with-python-version-on-ubuntu-14-04) in the same .py file I edited, but I know for a fact that if I try that it will lead to problems somewhere down the road somehow.  Also why does that quick install even download a blender version it can't work with to begin with?  While I'm at it I might as well as ask which version of blender does compile with python 3.8.10.  I can't seem to find that answer in any of the blender release notes.  Thank you for anyone willing to help me on this.  It is much appreciated.